# How to get a date value from angularjs form

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

**HTML**

```
<div align="center" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <form name="form" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
        <input type="date" name="myDate" ng-model="myDate" value="myDate"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('formExample', []);
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.myDate = new Date();
});
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var jtime = req.body.myDate;
    console.log(jtime);
});
```

Here the result(console.log) shows undefined. How to get that date value from angular js form.

Comment: simply $scope.myDate will do the trick.

Comment: Your code is perfect just replace req.body with $scope.myDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `$scope.submitForm` function making AJAX POST request using [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post):

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http.post('/', {myDate: $scope.myDate});
    };     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
     <input type="date" name="myDate" ng-model="myDate" value="myDate"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here `type="date"` adds a Date picker to that field

Once you select date through date picker `ng-model="myDate"` will be collected with selected date